# Getting an android app to detect NFC tags

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created an android app for reading NFC tags. 
It can detect if an NFC is around, however it can't read the contents on it nor can I write anything on it. I also have problem with my code on line 79 of the **read_write_successful** class. I made use of the "**createNdefMessage**" method that was declared on line 190.

Below is my code:

***read_write_successful class***

```
public class read_write_successful extends AppCompatActivity {


    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    ToggleButton tglReadWrite;
    TextView txtTagContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.mattie_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        tglReadWrite = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglReadWrite);
        txtTagContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTagContent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC intent received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)){
            if (tglReadWrite.isChecked()){
                Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

                if (parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0){
                    readTextFromMessage((NdefMessage)parcelables[0]);
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF messages found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(txtTagContent.getText() + "");

                byte[] payload = "my string".getBytes();
                NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createExternal("nfctutorials", "externaltype", payload);
                ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{ ndefRecord });

                writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    private void readTextFromMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
        NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();

        if (ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length > 0){

            NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
            String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);

            txtTagContent.setText(tagContent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF records found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, read_write_successful.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);
    }

    private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem(){
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    private void formatTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage){
        try{
            NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (ndefFormatable == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not ndef formatable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            ndefFormatable.connect();
            ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
            ndefFormatable.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag written!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("formatTag",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void writeNdefMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage){
        try{

            if (tag == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag object cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null){
                //format tag with the ndef format and writes the message.
                formatTag(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
            else {
                ndef.connect();
                if (!ndef.isWritable()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not writable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ndef.close();
                    return;
                }

                ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
                ndef.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag written!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("writeNdefMessage",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String content){
        try {
            byte[] language;
            language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().getBytes("UTF-8");

            final byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
            final int languageSize = language.length;
            final int textLength = text.length;
            final ByteArrayOutputStream payload = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1 + languageSize + textLength);

            payload.write((byte) (languageSize & 0x1F));
            payload.write(language, 0, languageSize);
            payload.write(text, 0, textLength);

            return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload.toByteArray());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Log.e("createNdefMessage",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String content){
        NdefRecord ndefRecord = createTextRecord(content);

        return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{ndefRecord});
    }

    public void tglReadWriteOnClick(View v){
        txtTagContent.setText("");
    }

    public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord){
        String tagContent = null;
        try {
            byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
            int languageSize = payload[0] & 51;
            tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1,
                    payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return tagContent;
    }
}
```

***MainActivity class***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private KeyStore keyStore;
    // Variable used for storing the key in the Android Keystore container
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "WERTY";
    private Cipher cipher;
    TextView mattie;
    Button Login;
    Button SignUp;
    Button NextButton;
    Button WriteButton;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    ToggleButton tglReadWrite;
    EditText txtTagContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logIn);
        SignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signUp);
        NextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        WriteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_write);
        mattie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMatma);
        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Praetoria D.otf");
        mattie.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_play_again).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // We normally won't show the welcome slider again in real app
                // but this is for testing
                PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());

                // make first time launch TRUE
                prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Initializing both Android Keyguard Manager and Fingerprint Manager
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);


        // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            // public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        // Check whether the device has a Fingerprint sensor.
        if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Lock Screen security not enabled in Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        genKey();
                    }

                    if (cipherInit()) {
                        FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                        Register assistance = new Register(this);
                        helper.startAuthentication(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                        assistance.startAuthentication(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        tglReadWrite = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglReadWrite);
        txtTagContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTagContent);
        if (nfcAdapter!=null && nfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not available! Kindly switch it on in your phone's settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void genKey() {
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
        try {
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,"AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7).build()
            );
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean cipherInit() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES+ "/" +KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC+ "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey)keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }

    public void signUpBtn(View v){
        Intent iv = new Intent(this, CardNumberSignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(iv);
    }
    public void loginBtn(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,LoginSuccessfulActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void nextBtn(View v){
        Intent ii = new Intent(this, register_security_successful.class);
        startActivity(ii);
    }

    public void writeBtn(View v){
        Intent iii = new Intent(this, read_write_successful.class );
        startActivity(iii);
    }

}
```

***read_write_successful layout [Relative Layout]***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout 



xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tglReadWrite"
        android:textOn="@string/txtOn"
        android:textOff="@string/txtOff"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="tglReadWriteOnClick"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtTagContent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tglReadWrite"
        android:inputType="text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @henrique romao, thanks for the formatting.

Comment: Please can someone help me out with my issue as soon as possible.  The method *createNdefMessage* was created but when I used it in the *onNewIntent* method, it was faint. It give me this hint when I hovered over it with my mouse:

Comment: The *onNewIntent* method at 'NdefMessage ndefMessage1 = createNdefMessage(txtTagContent.getText() + "");' it was faint. It gave me this hint when I hovered over it with my mouse: "Variable 'ndefMessage1' initializer 'createNdefMessage(txtTagContent.getText() + "")' is redundant less... to be continued below:

Comment: continues...This inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used after its assignment, i.e.:  - the variable never gets read after assignment OR  - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read OR  - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons) OR  - the variable is never used.'

Comment: I have been able to resolve my issue. I got help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462444/android-nfc-writing-doesnt-work-with-2-activities-but-works-with-1